# tableview cell with no content

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview

My table view is populating but without a content on the cell
when I try to put this line    `//cell.textLabel?.text = todoItems[indexPath.row]`. I am getting this error [check the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/97aH8.png)

```
// Cell creation

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

    cell.selectionStyle = .None
    let item = todoItems[indexPath.row]

    cell.delegate = self
    cell.toDoItem = item

    // modify the cell to have check mark
    if (item.completed) {

        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark
    }
    else {

        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.None
    }

    return cell
}



// Data source

class DataSource: NSObject {

    let itenName: String

    var completed : Bool
    var deadline : NSDate
    var UUID :String

    init(itenName :String , completed :Bool = false , deadline : NSDate , UUID :String  ) {
        self.itenName = itenName
        self.completed = completed
        self.UUID = UUID
        self.deadline = deadline
        //self.subTitle = subTitle
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You assign wrong type. You should do like this:

```
let item = todoItems[indexPath.row]
cell.textLabel?.text = item.itenName
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the class of todoItems[indexPath.row] is `DataSource` with

```
print(todoItems[indexPath.row].classForCoder)
```

And the class of cell.textLabel?.text is `String`.
So you assign the wrong type. You should do it like this:

```
cell.textLabel?.text = todoItems[indexPath.row].itenName
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation with your code. This response, as it is now, is not an answer and is being reviewed for deletion.

Comment: I have added a explanation with my code.Do you have more comments?

Answer (score -1):

You should do like this

```
let item = todoItems[indexPath.row] as DataSource
cell.textLabel?.text = item[indexPath.row].itenName
```